# A problem about polynomial approximation

Tags: real-analysis

For $f\in C[a,b]$ the nth error function $E_n (f)=\inf$ {$||f-g||_\infty|$ $g$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$}. 
Assume that $[a,b]=[0,1]$. Prove that $E_n (\cos(m\pi x))=1$ for all $n<m$.
I have been staring at this problem for 2 hours and do not see a way.

Comment: How many zeros does each function have?

Comment: I thought about that, and there are m zeros for $\cos(m\pi x)$, n zeros for the polynomial, and there has to be an interval where the polynomial is bounded below by 0 whereas the cosine function can go below 0, say -1, but I do not know how to write a proof with that.